# Sudden change in altitude during measurement with GNSS

Tags: gps, qfield, accuracy, altitude

We work For some time now we have been working with QField and the GNSS receiver from Emlid. We get the accuracy via bluethoot from the receiver to QField. Lately, however, the measurements have been making inexplicable leaps in altitude (sometimes over 20m). However, the accuracy according to the QField is always given and does not change. Does anyone know if the problem is in QField or in Emlid? Has anyone had this experience?

Comment: Did this happen after February 24 in Eastern part of Europe?

Answer (score 1):

Russia-Ukraine conflict. Reports exist of substantial jamming and spoofing of GNSS signals in Central and Eastern Europe.